# import a .js file and use a definition inside

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.4

My .js file path is : Project/config/database.js and contains :

```
module.exports = {
database: 'mongodb:/127.0.0.1:27017/project
}
```

my .py file path is : Project/script/initializeData.py 
I need to take the database value (mongo URL) and use it in my .py 
How can I take the database value and use it in my .py code?

im using python 3.4

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

That code would smell. I suggest you putting the common confoiguration in a common format like json.

Project/config/config.json:

```
{"database":"mongodb:/....."}
```

Project/config/database.js:

```
// do you even need this file
module.exports = require("./config")
```

Project/script/initializeData.py:

```
import json
with open('../config/config.json', 'r') as f:
  config = json.load(f)
database = config["database"]
```

Comment: I thought doing that , as I did it with other files , just the config.json file is used in so many scripts in different languages i thought maybe there is another way

Comment: Then call it `database-config.json`.